# Django Can't Resolve Style ine fil static

Tags: python, django, templates, static

Hello i can't resolve static file (vendor,bootstrap,css,js) i can t see the picture with color just baisc formular need help to resolve this i followed the documentation step by step but this step didnt work
 this is my code html :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    {% load static %}
    <title>Login V9</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{{ static
    'AppStage/images/icons/favicon.ico' }}"/>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static
      'AppStage/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static
     'AppStage/fonts/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' %}">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static
    'AppStage/fonts/iconic/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css' %}">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static
    'AppStage/vendor/animate/animate.css' %}">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static
    'AppStage/vendor/css-hamburgers/hamburgers.min.css' %}">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static
    'AppStage/vendor/animsition/css/animsition.min.css' %}">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static
    'AppStage/vendor/select2/select2.min.css' %}">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static
    'AppStage/vendor/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css' %} ">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static
     'AppStage/css/util.css' %} ">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static
     'AppStage/css/main.css' %} ">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
</head>
<body>


    <div class="container-login100" style="background-image: url('images/paul.jpg');">
        <div class="wrap-login100 p-l-55 p-r-55 p-t-80 p-b-30">
            <form class="login100-form validate-form">
                <span class="login100-form-title p-b-37">
                    Sign In
                </span>

                <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-20" data-validate="Enter username or email">
                    <input class="input100" type="text" name="username" placeholder="matricule">
                    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-25" data-validate = "Enter password">
                    <input class="input100" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="password">
                    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
                    <button class="login100-form-btn">
                        Sign In
                    </button>
                </div>





            </form>


        </div>
    </div>



    <div id="dropDownSelect1"></div>

<!--===============================================================================================-->
     <script src="{% static
     'AppStage/vendor/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js' %}"></script>

    <script src="{% static
     'AppStage/vendor/animsition/js/animsition.min.js' %}"></script>

     <script src="{% static
     'AppStage/vendor/bootstrap/js/popper.js' %}"></script>
     <script src="{% static
     'AppStage/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="{% static
     'AppStage/vendor/select2/select2.min.js' %}"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="{% static
     'AppStage/vendor/daterangepicker/moment.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static
     'AppStage/vendor/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js' %}"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="{% static
    'AppStage/vendor/countdowntime/countdowntime.js' %}"></script>



    </body>
    </html>
```

this is the file views.py

```
 from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
# Create your views here.

def Authenti(request):
    template = loader.get_template('authentification/index.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render(request=request))
```

the picture of hearchi of my project
     [1]: https://zupimages.net/up/19/29/dkik.png"tooltip"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first link is wrong

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'AppStage/images/icons/favicon.ico' %}"/>
```

use path for image,

```
.container-login100 {
    background: url("/AppStage/images/paul.jpg")
}
```

Comment: resolve error       <div class="container-login100" style="background-image: url('{% static \"AppStage/images/paul.jpg\" %}');">     tag start is not closed